# Angular4 fullcalendar how to updateEvent

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I have error when trying to update event on the fullcalendar angular2

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined
```

Angular2 fullcalendar installed and declare as CalendarComponent,

```
<div class="ibox-content" *ngIf="isLoaded">
<angular2-fullcalendar [options]="calendarOptions"></angular2-fullcalendar>          </div>
```

EventObject was created

```
let event = {
        id: this.editableTask.id,
        title: this.editableTask.name,
        start: this.editableTask.startDateTime,
        end: this.editableTask.planDateTime
      }

      console.log(event);
```

console.log output

```
id: 6, title: "tes3", start: "2017-10-14T16:55:33", end: "2017-10-15T16:55:33"}
```

used CalendarComponent as a ViewChild

```
@ViewChild(CalendarComponent) myCalendar: CalendarComponent;
```

and I create function for update event

```
updateEvent(event: any) {
    this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
  }
```

when I've try to call function with eventObject caught issue:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined
    at mutateEvent (fullcalendar.js:13769)
    at updateEvents (fullcalendar.js:13356)
```

Please could somebody help to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not get rid of this error, because fullcalendar, as I understand it, wraps around the updateEvent. Try using ng-fullcalendar, calling the function 'render'.

```
npm i ng-fullcalendar
```